# Issue inputing sas date as datalines

Tags: sas

I've the following code. Though I've entered 30jun1983 it gets saved as 30/jun/2020. And it is reading only when there's two spaces between the date values in the cards and if there's only one space it reads the second value as missing.

```
DATA DIFFERENCE;
infile cards dlm=',' dsd;
INPUT  DATE1 DATE9. Dt2 DATE9.;
FORMAT DATE1 DDMMYY10. Dt2 DDMMYY10.;
DIFFERENCE=YRDIF(DATE1,Dt2,'ACT/ACT');
DIFFERENCE=ROUND(DIFFERENCE);
CARDS;
11MAY2009  30jun1983
;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need colons on your input statement (to denote INformats), and also a comma in your datalines (you specified a comma as your DLM - delimiter):

```
DATA DIFFERENCE;
infile cards dlm=',' dsd;
INPUT  DATE1 :DATE9. Dt2 :DATE9.;
FORMAT DATE1 DDMMYY10. Dt2 DDMMYY10.;
DIFFERENCE=YRDIF(DATE1,Dt2,'ACT/ACT');
DIFFERENCE=ROUND(DIFFERENCE);
CARDS;
11MAY2009,30jun1983
;
RUN;
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it read the date at 30/jun/2020 when I added two delimiters?

Comment: When I tested this, it came out as 30JUN2019.